# jquery change elemnets value from iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Here is my page :

```
<iframe src="/index/player/0-4" id="iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

My iframe content

```
<div id='outerdiv'>
<iframe src="" id="frameID" span="" scrolling="no" height=""></iframe>
</div>
```

now i wanna change with  help of jquery 
scr="" span="" and height by pressing one button

I have this code :

```
<script>$("#button").click(function () { 
      $("#frameID").attr("src", "http://site.info");
});</script>
<script>$("#button").click(function(){
  $("#frameID").animate({
    height: "72px"
  }, 1500 ); 
});

</script>
```

bbut it works only if iframe is on the same page with code

Comment: You have an iframe within an iframe?

Comment: yes becouse my iframe has some css that i dont want to affect my page ..

Comment: Please consider checking your question for typos.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the control within iFrame

```
($("#iframe").contents().find("#frameID")).attr("src", "http://site.info");
```